# Java error: unreported exception ioexception must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, compiler-errors, try-catch, bufferedreader

I cannot find what is wrong with my code here it is

```
public class Library{

FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\Users\\Adi\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Hw 7Jan-13Jan\\Date.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

public void add(Publication p){
    if(counter < publication.length){
        publication[counter++]=p;        
    }
}

public boolean remove(int id){
    Publication p=null;

    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
        if(publication[i].getId()==id){
            p=publication[i];

            for(int j=0;j<counter-1;j++)
                publication[j]=publication[j+1];
                publication[counter-1]=null;
                counter--;
        return true;        
        }

            return false;}
```

}

I tried with `try{}` `catch{}` but then I got other error : `class,interface or enum expected`

Any help is appreciated!Thanks

P.S: I'm new to this IOException and try{} catch{}  :)

Comment: Look at the `FileReader` constructor you're using - it declares that it can throw `IOException`. How do you expect that to be propagated? How much do you understand about checked exceptions at the moment? (It's not really clear why you've got those fields of `fr` and `br` given that you don't use them anywhere else, mind you...)

Comment: Some method of your code throws the checked exception "IOException". This exception must be passed to the caller with ``throws IOException`` in the method header or caught with try and catch. You need to explicitly catch an IOException like this ``try { ... } catch(IOException e) { ... }``

Comment: Did you wrap  `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` instantiations in a try-catch block

Comment: yes, i tried to put  `public class Library throws IOException` and then i get "class,interface or enum expected"..

Comment: i am going to use the br later, but now i'm stuck with these errors

Comment: You cannot define exception throwing in "Class" definition. you can only use it with methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the problem is, you defined the FileReader fr  as a class variable. Then you will get an error to handle/define exception. when yo define try-catch for handle exception, another problem arise, ie., "Illegal start of type". For this you need to define/declare:

```
static{
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\Users\\Adi\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Hw 7Jan-13Jan\\Date.txt");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

or assign the FileReader in Constructor.

```
FileReader fr;

public Library(){
     try {
        fr = new FileReader("D:\\Users\\Adi\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Hw 7Jan-13Jan\\Date.txt");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
}
```